# Accessing image files on Windows server from php on Linux server

Tags: php, windows, image

I am currently hosting a php script on a public web server that I use to retrieve an image for me hosted locally on the same server. I was recently told I would need to do the same thing for another process, except our new process will need to pull images from a Windows server. Could anyone recommend the best way to go about doing this? I have tried just utilizing a direct path such as the following with no luck:

```
<?
  $im = file_get_contents('\\SERVER-NAME\Photos\image.jpg');
  header('content-type: image/gif');
  echo $im;
?>
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Install [Samba](http://www.samba.org/) and [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) it.

Comment: the question is, does the file_get_contents work or not. If it works you can use @Baba's answer, if it doesn't, play more with the path to get it work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `imagecreatefromstring` http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php

```
$data = file_get_contents('\\SERVER-NAME\Photos\image.jpg');
$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);

if ($im !== false) {
    header('Content-Type: image/gif');
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
}
```

Let me know if any error is generated .. so that i can help you further ...

**Edit 1**

A. `Warning: file_get_contents(\WINDOWS-SERVERNAME\Photos\image.jpg) [function.file-get-contents]:`

I can see you are trying to access `UNC paths` this would work if the network folders are allowed to be accessed by Apache user

B. `Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagecreatefromstring() in`

This means you don't have GD http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php installed on your PHP server since this is your linux machine you can run something like `# yum install php53u-gd`

Comment: Hi there, thanks very much for the input, I really appreciate it! I ran into the following error when running your code snippet: Warning: file_get_contents(\WINDOWS-SERVERNAME\Photos\image.jpg) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/SERVERNAME/html/photo.php on line 4

Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagecreatefromstring() in /var/www/vhosts/SERVERNAME/html/photo.php on line 5

Comment: What is the exact error .. that would help me know what am dealing with